# ASP.NET identity ConfirmEmailAsync only works on local

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to confirm the user email with ConfirmEmailAsync but it only works on my local. When I deploy the backend to Azure app service, it doesn't work, always is "Invalid Token".

How do I generate the email confirmation token ?

```cs
public async Task<string> GenerateConfirmedEmailTokenAsync(string email)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
    return await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
}
```

How do I confirm the email address?

```cs
public async Task<IdentityResult> ConfirmUser(string email, string token)
{
    var user = await GetUserByEmailAsync(email);
    return await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
}
```

In localhost works perfectly, but in Azure app service (windows) it doesn't.

The problem is not in the URL decode when I get the token from the URL because I tried that with postman with the same code that `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` has created and is always the same "Invalid Token".